# What is the right clock chip for making a speedometer with an AVR

Tags: avr, atmel, clock

I am building a hot rod and I decided to make a speedometer myself with a 3 digit nixietube display. I am planning on using an Atmel AVR microtroller (ATmega32 I beleive). I would like a CMOS clock that I can use to compare time for to keep the speedo as accurate as possibile.

1. What is a good clock chip to use?
2. How to I wire interface it to the AVR?
3. How do I properly use it in software?

Here is what I have so far:

- Pulse generator for transmission (sign wave, will use the self
  powered 4069 square wave converter circuit but power it off the ps
  not the wave)
- Nixie tubes and sockets
- Atmel microntroller and socket
- Nixie tube driver chips
- Programming socket for AVR

I would like to make one order to Mouser and get the hardware breadborded ASAP so any help is appreaciated.

Answer (score 4):

Your speedometer needs to measure the elapsed time between two pulses, and it doesn't need to know the time of day.

I'd consider using the AVR's calibrated internal oscillator. Its +-1% deviation from the nominal frequency is probably more precise than the circumference of your vehicle's tires.

If that's not good enough for you, spend an extra fifty cents for a crystal oscillator.

Comment: you only get +/- 1% deviation if you run the atmel calibration script on the chip, I believe

Comment: Maybe. I wrote my own calibration firmware only to find out the factory OSCCAL was only 1 off (not 1% off) from the perfect calibration. And the USART worked fine with or without the calibration.

Comment: Atmel factory "calibration" is only 10% accurate. They have an application note for upping that to 1%. PICs OTOH have factory calibration to 1%.

Answer (score 2):

I would not worry much about the AVR internal oscillator accuracy, it is good enough when compared with the tire inflation varying so much based on temperature of the day, the asphalt, how aggressive you drive, etc, it may change the circumference in serious percentage.  Once you can do the calibration and get the best you can from the gadget, it is okay.  An informative speedOmeter does just that, inform you, if it is showing 37mph instead of 36mph, that is not a dramatic or traumatic difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use the chips oscillator.  I did a similar thing (well I used a two line lcd display) with an old PIC.  The sensor on the transmission sent out so many thousands of pulses per mile, which gives you a fair amount of room to calibrate for tire size and gear ratios, etc.  So you could choose any number of solutions from measuring time between individual pulses to measuring 10 pulses or something like that, with a timeout where you clearly know the car has stopped and the speed is zero.  which you would need for any solution.  if you know or figure out the pulses per mile its not hard to do the math to figure out the time between pulses at different speeds and then add the plus or minus accuracy of the clock on the microcontroller to find out what your speed error is.  My guess is the analog and timing nature of the sensor and wires are themselves going to have as much error as the clock you are using as a reference.  (jitter in the pulses at a fixed rate).  You can also throw in slop in the drivetrain, variation in tire sizes (as you peel out, stress the tire with the brake or acellerator, etc), you are probably fine, I would start with the internal oscillator.

Using an external oscillator or the internal one you could have a timer count every second or something like that and count speedo ticks per second and update the display (tubes) based on that (instead of measuring between every speedo tick).  The biggest problem I had when I did this was not the sensing or timing of the pulses, I had a heck of a time doing the divide by tens to print the speed in decimal, hex was easy, octal even easier, but decimal when the program space was a kbyte or less and memory was measured in bytes. your avr likely has more resources than I had at the time and a good (and affordable) C compiler.

Would love to see pictures when you get it working...

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tips:

http://winavr.scienceprog.com/example-avr-projects/measuring-motor-speed-and-display-result-on-lcd.html

http://www.avrfreaks.net/index.php?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&p=642909

As others have said, you don't need a realtime clock unless you care about the date and time, you just need to measure the time between rotations.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
 I reviewed the links and i think we can do it without.  There is a speedo on the market that in order to calibrate you drive on the highway and hit a calibrate button once for 2 mile markers.  this will count how many pulses are in a mile and then we can calculate the speed based on those numbers and use speed buddy's to confirm.  Now all i need is some simple transistor and resistor selection and implementation done and i am ready to order.
  I want to also have hi voltage turn indicators using neon bulbs so i figured i would use 2 resistors the split the turn lamp voltage and then put that through a transistor.  I have a bunch of mpsa42 transistors i think will work.
Thanks
Ed

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't trust the onboard RC in an automotive application for measuring speed.  Look at the spec for drift over temperature.  What temperature extremes do you anticipate where you live or might travel?

A simple crystal and two caps will get you an oscillator that is far more accurate than you need.

A resonator would probably work well. Some have the capacitors built in. Lower cost than crystals usually, though for hobby projects I think that counting pennies is a little silly.

Answer (score 0):

I just finished a similar project for a friend, he bought a Golf Cart and wanted to install a SpeedOMeter on it.  It was simple.  I ask him to produce a disc that would be attached to one of the front tires, magnets embedded into the disc, a magnetic sensor (eBay).  The sensor changes its logical output whenever a magnet approaches its head.  He measured the tire circumference and gave me a ball park of 52.8 inches, what means one revolution per second means 3mph.  Based on that, I asked him to install 15 little magnets into the disc, if I capture pulses from the sensor during 200ms, it will give me 3 counts, so, 3mph.  It was easy. But it could require calibration, his measurements could be wrong, the running tire could have a different circumference, etc. No big deal.  He would be satisfied with two 7 segments blue LED display (1.5" tall) to indicate the speed. I choose a simple AtMega88 (in the drawer). The AtMega could drive the display directly, no need for transistors, if the current is not too much. The nice thing is that the blue big display uses two LEDs in series under each segment, what would have double brightness with the same single LED current. But there was a catch, two blue LEDs would require more than 5V, they require 6.3V to have a nice daylight brightness. He bought the 7 segments in Common Cathode version, what complicated things. The AtMega can not run on 6.3V, so we needed to create a virtual ground on +1.3Vdc for the AtMega, while the Display ground will be the real zero Volts. The solution was simple, feeding the AtMega with 6.3V, but its ZeroV would be connected to real ground via two 1N914 or 1N4148 simple silicon diodes.  The AtMega would have +5V or less between VCC and GND pins, and the display will be driven with 6.3V directly from the I/O port pins from the AtMega. It worked nicely.  Now, clock fuse to use internal 8MHz oscillator. Connected the pulse sensor directly to the T1 pin (PD5), programmed the counter to count when T1 pin goes up, constantly. Programmed Counter1 (16 bits) to count from a specific value, and interrupts when the counter reach zero, it gave me an interruption every 200ms.  On the interrupt routine, just read the T1 counter and zero it.  Store the read value into a 4 registers and push them forward, in order to keep only the last 4 readings on those registers. Then add them all and divided by four, simple done by logical shifting right twice. By doing this, it reduced the instability between 3 and 4 value on display for example.  Used a simple table of segments to lit on each of the double display, from -0 to 29 and voilá, just lookup the table from the value of the value average and dump it to the port pins driving the 7 segments display. Worked like a charm. Ah,the Golf Cart runs at top speed of 20mph, this is the reason of the table goes up to 29 only.   Calibration was done easily.  A simple jumper makes the AVR to disable the 200ms interrupt, count the pulses from T1 pin, starting from zero, while he drives the cart for exactly, excatly 22 feet, what is 264 inches. If the tire is exactly 52.8" in circumference, it will turn exactly 5 revolutions, exactly 75 pulses on the sensor. Now comes math. The counter1 overflows at each 200ms when loaded with certain value, that is the division of 8MHz with 256 prescaler, what is exactly number 31250. What I do now? multiply 31250 by 75 (that is a fixed constant of 2343750 = 0x23C346) and divide by the actual pulses counted during the 22 feet movement. Not willing to create a full havoc of 24 bits division, I just subtracted the pulses counter value from the 0x23C346 enough times to reach zero, this is not a calculation speed racing, it worked. Badabim. I will have the new value to load into the counter1 overflow, and have a different amount of time, 200ms or other, that counter1 overflow interrupts me to read value of counts of T1 pulses during such time. Easy. Now, all the user should do to calibrate, is insert a jumper, run the 22 feet and remove the jumper.  When removes the jumper, the calculation is done and the new counter1 value is stored in eeprom. Now, every time it powers up the unit, it reads the eeprom for the value for the counter1 overflows, and it is ready to go.  Easy, less than 100 bytes of programming in assembly.  I love this language.  He liked the idea of using an AVR, since at the beginning he wanted to do it using simple counters and timers in pure TTL logic.  Now he wants me to update the AVR to do blinker lamps control and timers, and so on.